# Windows Phone 8 - Center PanoramaItem.Header

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Panorama App for Windows Phone 8 and I got a small problem. I added an image to the header of one of my Panorama.Item (and it shows up fine) but I'd love it to be centered and not aligned left. I don't even know if it's possible or if you can't change the alignment at all. Here's the code for the header I'm talking about:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
   <Image x:Name="Logo" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tap="Logo_Tap" />
</phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
```

The HorizontalAlignment="Center"-Property unfortunately doesn't seem to do it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem.Header>     
                        <Grid Width="432">
                            <Image x:Name="Logo"
                                   Height="100"
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                   Tap="Logo_Tap" />
                        </Grid>
</phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about this, but wrapping it in a Grid and centering it within that Grid makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid using a hard coded width.  The proper way to do this would be to override the Template on the `PanoramaItem`, like this (They key part being changing the `HorizontalAlignment` on the `header` `ContentControl`)

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CenteredHeaderPanoramaItemTemplate" TargetType="phone:PanoramaItem">
    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="12,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ContentControl x:Name="header" CharacterSpacing="-35" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontSize="66" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" Margin="12,-2,0,38" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="headerTransform"/>
            </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
        </ContentControl>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then just assign the Template using a StaticResource

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Template="{StaticResource CenteredHeaderPanoramaItemTemplate}">
    <phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
        <Image x:Name="Logo" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tap="Logo_Tap" />
    </phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
    <Grid x:Name="PanoramaItemContent">
    </Grid>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I don't get all of it because I'm still pretty new to XAML itself, but I understand what you're shooting for. I tried to use this snippet in my code, but I'm getting an error I've no idea where it is coming from: `Unexpected ATTRIBUTE in parse rule PropertyElement ::= . PROPERTYELEMENT Content? ENDTAG..` Seems like I'm missing an endtag somewhere, but the markup seems fine in the editor. I only get this error after building the project. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to place your `ControlTemplate` in a Resources section.  On the top of the page add <Page.Resources> and put it inside there.

Answer (score 1):

```
<phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
<Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
   <Image x:Name="Logo" Height="100" Tap="Logo_Tap" />
</Grid>
</phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
```

try this