# Right align panorama header

Tags: c#, xaml, layout, windows-phone-8

It seems that there should be a very easy solution to this but I cannot find it and it's killing me ...

All I wanna do is to add a *right aligned* refresh button (or image, or whatever) to the `Header` of a `PanaromaItem` in a `Panorama`, so pressing it reloads the data. (look at the image below)

[image]

I tried overriding the `PanoramaItem.Header`:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="first item" />
        <Image source="blah" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
    </Grid>
</phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
```

and I tried using `Grid`, `StackPanel`, `ViewPanel` and every other layout controller that I knew and couldn't achieve this unless I set a constant `width`.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you find a working solution to this problem? I tried everything suggested but still no luck.

Comment: I posted a good solution, no hard coded values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might as well answer this one correctly, just incase someone needs it.

You need to override the PanoramaItemStyle and set the Header ContentControl to Stretch.

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

That way when you apply the template it will cover the whole width.  Here is the full Override Style Template.

---

```XAML
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Chubs_PanoramaItemStyle" TargetType="phone:PanoramaItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:PanoramaItem">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl x:Name="header" CharacterSpacing="-35" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontSize="66" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" Margin="12,-2,0,38" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="headerTransform"/>
                            </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                        </ContentControl>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

---

Now apply that style to the PanoramaItem like so

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Style="{StaticResource Chubs_PanoramaItemStyle}">
    <phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="header1"/>
            <Image Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Image>
        </Grid>
    </phone:PanoramaItem.Header>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

---

And Screenshot of the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried horizontalalign="Right" is not working but to achive this you could set left margin:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="My Books" Foreground="LightGray" Margin="-10,0,0,0">
                    <phone:PanoramaItem.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Foreground="#72C158" Text="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="0,30,0,0" FontSize="55" FontFamily="/Font/BKANT.TTF#Book Antiqua"  TextAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal"/>
                            <Button Height="50" Width="50" Margin="130,20,0,0"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </phone:PanoramaItem.HeaderTemplate>
    </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I mentioned in the Q, I'm trying to avoid setting a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

By default when we set horizontal alignment to the image within panorama item header then it is not working But we can fix the width of the header textblock and set the alignment right for the image.

```
      <controls:PanoramaItem.Header>

                    <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="First" Width="400"/>
                        <Image Source="/ApplicationIcon.png" Width="60" Height="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                    </Grid>

            </controls:PanoramaItem.Header>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I mentioned in the Q, I'm trying to avoid setting a constant width.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20426360/3003945), you will need to override the pivotitem template to set the HorizontalAlignment of the Header to Stretch.
After that you should be able to align stuff to the right of the header.